# How does the order of execution differs for Professional edition

Tags: apex, trigger, professional-edition

I had an interview recently, where I was asked does order ID execution differs for Professional edition and it does which part it does.

I said it doesn't, order of execution is similar for all editions. But I was wrong, can someone explain me, Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it differs, if the edition is Professional Edition. PE doesn't have Triggers.

UE- Unilimited Edition
EE - Enterprise Edition

1. Old record loaded from database (or initialized for new inserts)
2. New record values overwrite old values
3. System Validation Rules (If inserting Opportunity Products, Custom     Validation Rules will also fire in addition to System Validation Rules)
4. All Apex before triggers (EE / UE only)
5. Custom Validation Rules
6. Record saved to database (but not committed)
7. Record reloaded from database
8. All Apex after triggers (EE / UE only)
9. Assignment rules
10. Auto-response rules
11. Workflow rules
12. Processes
13. Escalation rules
14. Parent Rollup Summary Formula value updated (if present)
15. Database commit
16. Post-commit logic (sending email)

Comment: Okay, so exclusion of triggers is what the difference is.

Comment: @SFDev I'm pretty sure the interviewer was incorrect, though. Just because you can't build Triggers in Professional Edition doesn't mean they can't be installed via a managed ISV package. The documentation doesn't state that triggers don't work in PE.

Comment: @c.Praveen kumar http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/151958/trigger-modification-in-salesforce?noredirect=1#comment222431_151958 can you please guide me

Comment: Sorry, I cannot access that link. It says Page not found